# Margin sizes changing per page when printing html (IE 8-11)

Tags: html, css

I have a user generated report page that is sometimes printed off, but it has a bizarre bug one internet explorer.  The page is set as tables within a series of divs that appear on the website at all the same sizes and formats, however when printing with IE each page "shrinks" a little more.  It may be that the margins are growing, but the relative font size and proportions of the table seem accurate in that they shrink with the pages.  I have tried disabling the shrink to fit option, but that did not help.  Has anyone run into a similar bug?  I have been searching for a while but most of the related problems' fixes have not helped.

Comment: Please post a small example to depict your problem, rather than just posting a bunch of text !

Comment: I tried, not enough rep for me to include an image in the OP.  I can maybe include an image link here?  [Try this for an example](http://i.imgur.com/iMsu3Fi.png) where the grey boxes are all page content.

Answer (score 0):

looked in to your page, what i think that is causing the shrinking of the page is the extra space at the end of the page.

[image]